# How to remove unwanted words in string preceding a expression?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract strings with a selected words only using regex in R.

Eg:

```
SLIM SSD POWER ADAPTER
  8.4L 1ST 3.5 HDD POWER ADAPTER
  SATA POWER ADAPTER FOR ODD/2HDD
  SLIM SSD SATA&POWER ADAPTER
  SATA POWER ADAPTER FOR HDD
  2ND 3.5 HDD+SSD POWER ADAPTER
  SATA POWER ADAPTER
  1ND 3.5 HDD+SSD POWER ADAPTER
  DUAL NET CARD SATA POWER ADAPTER
 POWER ADAPTER (Others)
```

i want to extract anything with a prefix or suffix to "POWER ADAPTER" expect the strings above "DUAL NET CARD SATA POWER ADAPTER" ,
 I tried using look behind negative , still couldn't get the desired extraction

Thanks

Comment: Please include the code you tried.  Why do you only expect the second to last line as the output?

Comment: Do you want to extract or remove in the end? Please provide a reproducible example and an exact expected output for the given sample input.

Comment: I tried to use (?<![A-Z] )POWER ADAPTER as regex , but it doesn't extract "DUAL NET CARD SATA POWER ADAPTER"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` function with `value = TRUE` argument as below:

```
strs <- c("SLIM SSD POWER ADAPTER", "POWER CORD", "LEAST SQUARE", "8.4L 1ST 3.5 HDD POWER ADAPTER", "SATA POWER ADAPTER FOR ODD/2HDD", "SLIM SSD SATA&POWER ADAPTER", 
"SATA POWER ADAPTER FOR HDD", "2ND 3.5 HDD+SSD POWER ADAPTER", 
"SATA POWER ADAPTER", "1ND 3.5 HDD+SSD POWER ADAPTER", "DUAL NET CARD SATA POWER ADAPTER", "POWER ADAPTER (Others)", "RICHIE", "MONITOR")

grep("POWER ADAPTER", strs, value = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
 [1] "SLIM SSD POWER ADAPTER"           "8.4L 1ST 3.5 HDD POWER ADAPTER"   "SATA POWER ADAPTER FOR ODD/2HDD" 
 [4] "SLIM SSD SATA&POWER ADAPTER"      "SATA POWER ADAPTER FOR HDD"       "2ND 3.5 HDD+SSD POWER ADAPTER"   
 [7] "SATA POWER ADAPTER"               "1ND 3.5 HDD+SSD POWER ADAPTER"    "DUAL NET CARD SATA POWER ADAPTER"
[10] "POWER ADAPTER (Others)"
```